# RxSwift: Mapping a completable to single observable?

Tags: ios, rx-swift

I am trying to do a couple of actions in sequence, using RxSwift and am unsure how to get it working.

The problem is returning a `Single` observable, where the success/error depends on whether a `Completable` call succeeds or fails.

My code attempt looks roughly like this:

```
func doSomething(with value: SomeType) -> Single<SomeType> {
    return repository.replace(with: value) // replace() returns a completable
        .asObservable()
        .flatMap { () -> Single<SomeType> in
            return Single.just(value)
    }
}
```

Error on line 4 (flatMap):

> Cannot convert call result type 'Observable<_.E>' to expected type 'PrimitiveSequence< SingleTrait, SomeType >' (aka 'PrimitiveSequence< SingleTrait, SomeType >')

How can I map this completable to a single?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Just a few months after I answered this question, a new operator was added to the Completable type. `.andThen`. Using it makes this code much simpler:

```
func doSomething(with value: SomeType) -> Single<SomeType> {
    return repository.replace(with: value)
        .andThen(Single.just(value))
}
```

### Origional Answer Follows:

Hmm... A Completable never emits an element so there is nothing to flatMap to. I.E. it doesn't make sense to even use the `flatMap` operator on a Completable. The only thing you can really do with it is subscribe to it.

Therefore, you need to implement your method like this:

```
func doSomething(with value: SomeType) -> Single<SomeType> {
    return Single<SomeType>.create { observer in
        return repository.replace(with: value)
            .subscribe(onCompleted: {
                observer(.success(value))
            }, onError: {
                observer(.error($0))
            })
    }
}
```

I've tried to work with Observables that don't emit values in the past, before these newfangled types, and I've always found them to be a pain. If I were you, I would convert your `replace` method to return a `Single<Void>` instead of a `Completable`. i.e.:

```
func replace(with value: SomeType) -> Single<Void>
```

If you do that, then you can simply:

```
func doSomething(with value: SomeType) -> Single<SomeType> {
    return repository.replace(with: value).map { value }
}
```

Of course if you can do that, then you might as well have `replace(with:)` itself return a `Single<SomeType>`.

Comment: Thanks, I figured as much and implemented it the same as you suggested. I will give Completable a few more chances, then make an assessment .

Answer (score 19):

I am not sure about RxSwift, but in RxJava you could to the following

```
repository.replace(with: value).andThen(Single.just(value))
```